# jQuery UI Calendar closes on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In my web based CRM I've got an iframe with a jQuery calender which is working great on higher resolutions, but people on lower resolutions have to scroll to see the full calendar as either the top or bottom half appears. The problem is the calendar closes when they scroll as I guess it loses focus. Does anyone know of a way to keep it open until they've clicked a date?

Answer (score 0):

the only serious way to prevent the blur from the input or datepicker is to comment the line with the blur in the plugin and create a own button like "close datepicker" and call the blur function there.

there are some other ways like refocusing the calendar on click on some element. but i think its not possible to detect a scrollbar click.

keep in mind that its not a bug if datepicker blurs on a click outside the element where the calendar is created or the calendar itself. sorry maybe you post this as a nice feature to have to jqueryUI developer team.

Comment: I would only want it to stay open in specific places i.e. where it could appear of screen. There's only 2 places in the CRM where this happens at the moment. The other places it's fine to let it close on its own